# How to add ImageView array to ArrayAdapter for a Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a customised row layout containing a Imageview and TextView for a List view.
I can add a array of strings representing each row to the ArrayAdater but am having trouble populating the row ImageViews.

I have tried creating a ImageView array and added to ArrayAdaptor as follows (as I could not see a ArrayAdpter constructor that takes two Arrays as arguments):

```
// a string array holding the list items
    String classes[] = { "My Profile", "Splash", "Log A Dive", "Search Dives",
            "Weather: Magic Seaweed", "Irish Tides", "International Tides", "Dive PLanner" };// each class is a menu Actiitem

    ImageView images[]={(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logdive),(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logdive2),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logdive3),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.search),(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.weather),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.tides),(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.tides)
            ,(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.logdive3)};

ArrayAdapter listadaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMenu.this,
                R.layout.single_list_row, R.id.title, classes);
        listadaptor.add(images);
setListAdapter(cutsomAdaptor);
```

Logcat Stack track:

> 01-02 05:10:45.480: E/AndroidRuntime(891): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mooney.diveapp/com.mooney.diveapp.MainMenu}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What is **customAdaptor** and what is **listAdaptor** ??

Comment: And in your **cutsomAdaptor** what you have added??? And Clarify about **cutsomAdaptor** and **listAdaptor**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of an adapter is to link a set of data to a set of views (which are created by the AdapterView i.e. ListView) - you don't give it an array of views to use.

In this case, you need to override your ArrayAdapter's `getView` method which populates the layout. You need a data set which can represent both a String and an int (for the drawable resource ID), something like a [Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) (not ideal but for simplicity):

```
ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> classes = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
classes.add(Pair.create("My Profile", R.drawable.myProfile));
// add all items
ArrayAdapter listadaptor = new ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, Integer>>(MainMenu.this,
            R.layout.single_list_row, R.id.title, classes) {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflator.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_row, container, false);
        }
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Pair<String, Integer> item = getItem(position);
        title.setText(item.first);
        title.setCompoundDrawables(item.second, 0, 0, 0);
        return convertView;
    }
 };
```

Comment: That's allot clearer now, I get the link between the adapter and the list view, and also array list could represent a paired data set !

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my code it will be help to solve your problem.. for that i created three class
first one is Nameing class.

public class Nameing {

```
int image1;
String name;

public void setImage1(int image1) {
    this.image1 = image1;
}

public int getImage1() {
    return image1;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

second class is Adapter class

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
ArrayList<Object> item;
public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;
Context c;

public Adapter(ArrayList<Object> item, Activity context) {

    this.item = item;
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return item.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return item.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image1;
    TextView name;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    holder.image1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    final Nameing n = (Nameing) item.get(position);
    holder.image1.setImageResource(n.getImage1());
    holder.name.setText(n.getName());

    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, n.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

}

and third class is MainActivity.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private ListView list;

private ArrayList<Object> item = new ArrayList<Object>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    Arraylist();

    Adapter ad = new Adapter(item, MainActivity.this);
    list.setAdapter(ad);

}

private void Arraylist() {
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image1, "name");
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image2, "name");
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image3, "name");
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image4, "name");
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image5, "name");
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image6, "name");
    AddOjectToList1(R.drawable.image7, "name");

}

void AddOjectToList1(int image1, String name) {

    Nameing n = new Nameing();
    n.setImage1(image1);
    n.setName(name);
    item.add(n);
}
```

}